# How to assign default value to a property

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, servicestack

CustomerService is a webservice and it is getting called successfully but I am unable to access SelectCommand in the Any method. I think I am missing something here, could anyone suggest.

```
public class CustomerService : Service
{
  private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection; // injected successfully
  public ServiceCommand SelectCommand {get;set;}

  public CustomerService(IDBConnection dbConnection)
  {        
         _dbConnection = dbConnection;            
  }

  public Customer Any(CustomerRequest request)
  {
       //_dbconnection is available           

       //but selectcommand is null here   

       //db operations     

  }
}


[Route("/customers")]
public class CustomerRequest
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceCommand
{
    public string SQL { get; set; }        
    public CommandType CommandType { get; set; }

    public ServiceCommand()
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    }
}
```

I've initialized the connection by inheriting `AppHostBase`

```
  public override void Configure(Container container) {
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
          c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString,
                                            SqlServerDialect.Provider));

        container.Register<IDbConnection>(c => c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection()).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
      }
```

When I tried to write unit test by setting SelectCommand explicitly, it works. But I am unable to test how it works by not setting the value, I assumed it takes the default value set in the constructor.

```
 var service = new CustomerService(InMemoryTestDatabase.OpenDbConnection());
 service.SelectCommand = new ServiceCommand() { SQL = "SELECT * FROM customers" };
```

**Edit**

IDbConnection in the constructor is working fine but my problem is with SelectCommand which is a public property here. My intention is, if the webservice is called normally I'd hit the actual database by setting query like below in the constructor.

```
SelectCommand = new ServiceCommand() {Text = "sp_getcustomers"};
```

But when I test it, I would set it to sqllite database and change my query to table "select * from customers" since sqllite doesn't support sp's. As mentioned unit tests are working fine, but the service is not able to initialize the public properties.

If I initialize a private readonly property same as _dbConnection like below, it works fine but I would like to inject command for the service explicitly.

```
private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;
private readonly ServiceCommand _selectCommand;
public CustomerService(IDBConnection dbConnection)
{
   __dbConnection = dbConnection;
   _selectCommand = new ServiceCommand(){Text = "sp_getCustomers"};
}
```

Comment: Are you using a DI container in your application? It may be injecting null value.

Comment: Is there a default constructor(that does not set SelectCommand)? Or is there any other places where SelectCommand may be set to null?

Comment: Why don't you just use the constructor before using the `Any` method?

Comment: `SelectCommand = new SeriveCommand();` is a typo, right? You meant `SelectCommand = new ServiceCommand();`?

Comment: No, DI container is not injecting null

Comment: There is no default constructor and SeriveCommand is a typo, rectified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to include all relevant info and context about your question as this would be impossible to infer without out-of-hand knowledge on how you're using it. E.g. what does your IOC look like?

You're asking for an `IDbConnection` in your constructor:

```
public CustomerService(IDBConnection dbConnection)
{
     SelectCommand = new ServiceCommand();
}
```

But it's very likely you're only registering an `IDbConnectionFactory`, so there doesn't exist any registered dependency with `IDbConnection`.

If you inheriting from [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs) class you've already got the `IDbConnectionFactory` injected and access to the `IDbConnection` with the [base.Db property](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs#L74):

```
private IDbConnection db;
public virtual IDbConnection Db
{
    get { return db ?? (db = TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open()); }
}
```

#### All public properties get injected by the IOC

The reason why **SelectCommand** property is null is because it's a public property. All of your Services public properties are attempted to be resolved by your Registered dependencies and because you don't have any registered dependencies of type `ServiceCommand` it is overrided with null. If this was defined in your constructor instead it would've thrown a run-time exception, because it's just a property it's initialized to null.

If you change the visibility of `SelectCommand` to protected, private, internal or static it wont be attempted to be injected by the IOC.

Comment: No, I've used injection for IDbConnection and it is instantiating fine.

Comment: I've added information about the issue I am facing. Could you please take a look into it.

Comment: Just looking at it, your `Any()` method is invalid since it doesn't have a Request DTO.

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to replicate my implementation via. CustomerService. So, posting only details I am having issue with. Right now, "SelectCommand" public property is not initialized propertly other than that rest of the service is working fine. IDbConnection is initialized and request is also routed correctly with parameters, but db calls fail since command is not getting initialized.

Comment: I've now provided all details of my implementation, please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @Sundeep Updated my answer. Change the visibility of your property to be non-public.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've exposed it as public property since I am passing sqllite query to the command. So, are there any other alternatives to achieve this, I think my test cases wont work if I change it to any of the mentioned access modifiers.

Comment: I've updated (above), Any method of customerservice to retrieve the property if it is null. It works for service and test cases as well, can you provide your thoughts on this. Also, please share if you have any better ideas.

Comment: @Sundeep I keep answering your question and you keep changing it? Now the original question is highly confusing - ask a new more specific question, be clear and concise and include all context. Your questions require much more effort than they should.

Comment: I've posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749904/set-public-properties-in-servicestack-web-services#