# Set non-read only property in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to set a public property in the service constructor, it is giving null reference exception in the Any() method. If I changed it to readonly field, it is working fine. But I would like to set this property by instantiating the service, could anyone provide insights how this can be achieved.

```
public class CustomerService : Service
{
   private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;
  public ServiceCommand SelectCommand {get;set;}
  public CustomerService(IDBConnection dbConnection)
  {
         SelectCommand = new ServiceCommand();
         _dbConnection = dbConnection;            
  }

  public Customer Any()
  {
          //selectcommand is null here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've partially answered this in [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745940/85785).

#### All public properties get injected by the IOC

The reason why SelectCommand property is null is because it's a **public property**. All of your Services public properties are attempted to be resolved by your Registered dependencies and because you don't have any registered dependencies of type `ServiceCommand` it is overrided with null. If this was defined in your constructor instead it would've thrown a run-time exception, because it's just a property it's **set to null**.

If you change the visibility of SelectCommand to be **non-public**, e.g. protected, private, internal or static it wont be attempted to be injected by the IOC.