# Set public properties in ServiceStack web services

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to write unit tests for ServiceStack services using Sqlite. Since Sqlite doesn't support stored procedures, I've created public property of type 'ServiceCommand' that takes command text and command type as inputs. By default it is configured to run stored procedure and while writing unit test cases, I am re-assigning the SelectCommand property to sql query against sqlite before calling `Any()` method as below. All test cases work fine.

```
var request = new CustomerRequest() { name = "alfki"  };
var service = new CustomerService(InMemoryTestDatabase.OpenDbConnection());
service.SelectCommand = new ServiceCommand() { SQL = "SELECT * FROM customers where customerid = {0}" };
var result = service.Any(request);
```

But per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745074/how-to-assign-default-value-to-a-property), public properties of CustomerService are set to null by IOC while resolving the references thus SelectCommand is null in `Any()` method resulting in object reference error. By setting the property as protected, private, internal or static, I will not be able to run unit tests.

```
public class CustomerService : Service
{
  private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;
  public ServiceCommand SelectCommand {get;set;}

  public CustomerService(IDBConnection dbConnection)
  {        
         _dbConnection = dbConnection;  //injected successfully
         SelectCommand =  new ServiceCommand(){ SQL = "sp_getcustomers",
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};          
  }

  public Customer Any(CustomerRequest request)
  {
        //Select command is not accessible here.

  }
}


[Route("/customers")]
public class CustomerRequest
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**ServiceCommand**

```
public class ServiceCommand
{
    public string SQL { get; set; }        
    public CommandType CommandType { get; set; }

    public ServiceCommand()
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    }
}
```

To be able to run test cases and service as well, I've modified `Any()` method to instantiate ServiceCommand if it is null. I would like to know if this is the way to go or any better alternatives.

```
public class CustomerService : Service
{
  private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection; // injected successfully
  public ServiceCommand SelectCommand {get;set;}

  public CustomerService(IDBConnection dbConnection)
  {        
         _dbConnection = dbConnection;  //injected successfully         
  }

  public Customer Any(CustomerRequest request)
  {
        SelectCommand = SelectCommand ?? new ServiceCommand() { SQL = "sp_getCustomers",CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) services will inject registered IOC properties for all public properties it will override the value you set in the constructor so you can't make it a public property without registering it in the IOC since it will be overridden to null.

Given this, some possible options are:

#### Make it a public field

```
public class CustomerService : Service
{
    public ServiceCommand SelectCommand = new ServiceCommand { 
       SQL = "sp_getcustomers", 
       CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
    ...
}
```

#### Inject a read-only property with a setter

```
service.SetSelectCommand(
  new ServiceCommand { SQL = "SELECT * FROM customers where customerid = {0}" });
```

#### Register it in your IOC and specify it in your constructor

```
container.Register(new ServiceCommand { 
   SQL = "sp_getcustomers", 
   CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure });
```

and change constructor to:

```
public CustomerService(IDBConnection dbConnection, ServiceCommand serviceCommand)
{        
    _dbConnection = dbConnection; 
    _serviceCommand = serviceCommand;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew about first option but as services increase, it will be difficult to maintain. I preferred second option.